# How to specify port of my server to Angular application? (Angular 10)

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a simple Angular application (Angular 10), and a simple server written in NodeJs. My server application runs on port 3000, and my Angular application runs on port 4200. I have created proxy.conf.json file, specified url of my server. But how do I make http client do request not to localhost:4200, but to localhost:3000 ?

Comment: Start your requests with `http://localhost:3000/...`

Comment: what is the main problem now, you can run angular and node concurrently?

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if the issue is solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution A (Not best practice)**

If you want you can hardcode it in the http request

```
this.httpClient.get(
           "http://localhost:3000/your path", { responseType: 'text' }
        )
```

**Solution B**  (used as property but same for all stages)

You can extract the base url path to environment in environment.ts

```
export const environment = { 
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
  production: false
};
```

And then use it in your service

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
this.httpClient.get(
               environment.apiUrl +"/your path", { responseType: 'text' }
            )
```

**Solution C** (Same as solution B but will give you different properties for different stages)

If you want different apiUrl for dev and production you can use different environments for example environment.dev.ts , environment.prod.ts
Then in your angular.json you can configure those environments as

```
"production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
}

 "dev": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]
}
```

Then you can choose what environment gets executed with ng serve with the command

```
ng serve --configuration=dev -> dev environment loaded
ng serve --configuration=production -> production environment loaded
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to serve your angular application on your NodeJS server.

ng serve on port 4200 and it is just for you to do hot testing.